# How to insert multiple rows from a textarea in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, insert, textarea

```
<html>
<form method="POST" action="insertlines.php">
<textarea name="url" rows="10" ></textarea>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Enter">
</form>
</html>
```

How can i put every single row of the textarea into a MySQL row ?

The thing I want is when I input:

```
John
Peter
Steven
```

in the textarea, I want them in my database with different ids each.

Comment: Assuming what you mean is the entire text within *one* textarea field, you need to set up your field in phpmyadmin to be a "TEXT" datatype, and not a varchar, which is what I assume you have.  Or do you have more than one textarea that you need looped into the database?

Comment: The thing I want is when I input:

John
Peter
Steven
"separated with enters"
in the textarea, I want them in my php database with different id's each.

Comment: Then what you have should work, as long as you have set your datatypes properly as I mentioned.  **Note**, you are vulnerable to SQL injection, as you are including the variable directly in the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to parse the text, looking for the "enter" character:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['url'])){
    if(strpos($_POST['url'], "\n")){
        $entries = explode("\n", $_POST['url']);
    } else {
        $entries = array($_POST['url']);
    }
    // connect to DB here
    // then iterate over entries
    foreach($entries as $e){
        // build some type of Prepared Statement to protect from SQL Injection
        $q = "INSERT INTO table (col1) VALUES (?)";
        // bind $e to statements
        // Execute SQL statements
    }
    // close DB connection
}
?>
```

Comment: you missed one bracket on the third line.

Comment: @KaloqnTerziev Fixed. The `?` can be used when you are using MySQLi Prepared Statements. Since you did not indicate how you were connecting to the SQL DB or what type of DB it was, I had to make some guesses.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$textarea=$_POST['url']
$sql = 'INSERT INTO YourTable(field1,field2,name) VALUES';
foreach(explode("\n", $textarea) as $row) {
$sql.='("field1","field2",.'$row'.)';
} 
$conn->query($sql)
```

Comment: This answer does not assign each to a new row and also does not protect against SQL Injection.

Comment: You'll need commas to delimit each set of values. Also, what purpose do "field1" and "field2" serve?

Comment: @mo.dhouibi I was not commenting on your code, it does work. The result would not answer OP's question. Your answer would submit each entry to a new column, not a new row. If the number of columns is less than the number of entries, the query would fail.

Comment: I understand , Thanks guys