# How to insert multiple row from textareas in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, insert-into

i cant insert to mysql from two textarea (both every row),

first this is a add.html

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="func/insert.php">
<table>
<tr>
<td>text 1</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><textarea class="custom" rows="10" cols="80" name="text1" id="text1" required></textarea>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>text 2</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><textarea class="custom" rows="10" cols="80" name="text2" id="text2" required>
</textarea></td>
</tr>
</table>
</from>
```

and then insert.php

```
<?php
include"connection.php";
if(isset($_POST['text1'])){
if(strpos($_POST['text1'], "\n")){
$entrytext1 = explode("\n",$_POST['text1']);
}
else{
$entrytext1 = array($_POST['text1']);
}
foreach ($entrytext1 as $linetext1){
$sql="INSERT INTO data(text1,text2)VALUES('$linetext1','$_POST[text2]')";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
if ($result){
echo"<script>alert(\"Success ...\");window.location='../index.php'</script>";
}
else{
echo"<script>alert(\"Failed ...\");self.history.back()</script>";
}
}
}
?>
```

well, i get a reference from [How to insert multiple rows from a textarea in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31925222/how-to-insert-multiple-rows-from-a-textarea-in-mysql)

So, how can i put every row (text1 and text2) of the textarea into a MySQL row? please help me anyone

Comment: BTW: MYsql functions are deprecated. You have very dangerous and injectable queries. Please use PDO.

Comment: What happens if you have say, 25 lines in 1 box and 3 in the other?

Answer (score 0):

You had some html errors as well as unsecure query execution. Try this:
**HTML**

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="func/insert.php">
<table>
<tr>
<td>text 1</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><textarea class="custom" rows="10" cols="80" name="text1" id="text1" required></textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>text 2</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><textarea class="custom" rows="10" cols="80" name="text2" id="text2" required>
</textarea></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

**PHP**

```
include"connection.php";
if(isset($_POST['text1'])){
    if(strpos($_POST['text1'], "\n")){
        $entrytext1 = explode("\n",$_POST['text1']);
    }
    else{
        $entrytext1 = array($_POST['text1']);
    }
    foreach ($entrytext1 as $linetext1){
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO data(text1,text2)VALUES(:text1, :text2)");
        $result = $stmt->execute(array('text1' => $linetext1, 'text2'    =>  $_POST['text2']));
        if ($result){
        echo"<script>alert(\"Success ...\");window.location='../index.php'</script>";
        }
        else{
            echo"<script>alert(\"Failed ...\");self.history.back()</script>";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object

Comment: You should first migrate from mysql to mysqli in your connection.php and try this.