# Inserting multiple rows/columns from a textarea in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

This is kind of confusing so I hope that I'm clear.

I recently visited a website that gave instructions on how to format text in a textarea and it inserted data into multiple fields and multiple rows of a database.

For example, in a text area, you would enter:

```
Data 1a, Data 2a, Data 3a
Data 1b, Data 2b, Data 3b
Data 1c, Data 2c, Data 3c
```

When it was submitted, Data 1 went into a data_1 column, Data 2 went into a data_2 column, and Data 3 went into a data_3 column. There were three rows inserted as well.

Has anyone ever done anything like this?

I saw these but they don't seem to cover the multiple fields in the same row:

[MySQL insert from a textarea to multiple rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37711880/mysql-insert-from-a-textarea-to-multiple-rows)
[How to insert multiple row from textareas in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33893919/how-to-insert-multiple-row-from-textareas-in-mysql)

Comment: you just use `explode(",", $textarea);` and make a array and then use one by one to insert your record :)

Comment: But that will explode on a per line basis, not lines. So, do I need to do 2 explodes? 1 for lines and then another for each field in each line?

Comment: no you just add comma after 3rd and 6th value and check with single explode and also use str_replace for remove \r\n

Comment: But how will that insert 3 fields in 3 new rows?

Comment: IMHO you have to do 2 explodes - one for lines/rows/SQL statements and second for fileds. Also consider how to escape delimiters and quotes if someone uses them inside your textarea

Comment: I'd probably just use a pipe instead of a comma.

Comment: You can create an INSERT statement by just using `str_replace()` ;-) A CSV parser would also do a good job.

Answer (score 0):

Given the sample data:

```
$input = 'Data 1a, Data 2a, Data 3a
Data 1b, Data 2b, Data 3b
Data 1c, Data 2c, Data 3c';
```

Simple way:

```
$lines = explode("\n", $input);
$data = [];
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    $items = explode(",", $line);
    $row = [];
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        $row[] = trim($item);
    }
    $data[] = $row;
}
```

Short way:

```
$data = array_map(function($row){
    return preg_split("/\\s*,\\s*/", $row);
}, explode("\n", $input));
```

Or better:

```
$data = array_map(function($line){
    return array_map('trim', str_getcsv($line));
}, explode("\n", $input));
```

`str_getcsv()` can do more than `explode()` or `preg_split()`. For example a value can contain a comma if it's quoted (like `Data 1a, "Data, 2a", Data 3a`)

In any case your `$data` array will look like:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => 'Data 1a',
    1 => 'Data 2a',
    2 => 'Data 3a',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    0 => 'Data 1b',
    1 => 'Data 2b',
    2 => 'Data 3b',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    0 => 'Data 1c',
    1 => 'Data 2c',
    2 => 'Data 3c',
  ),
)
```

Now you can loop through the data and insert it into DB. Don't forget to validate and escape (or use prepared statements). You probably want to show the user an error, if something is wrong with the data.

If you can trust the data (you usually shouldn't), you can modify the given string to an INSERT statement by just replacing some patterns:

```
$sql = preg_replace('/,\\s*/', "', '", $input);
$sql = preg_replace('/\\n/', "'), \n('", $sql);
$sql = "('" . $sql . "')";
$sql = "insert into my_table (c1, c2, c3) values \n" . $sql;
```

`$sql` will now look like:

```
insert into my_table (c1, c2, c3) values 
('Data 1a', 'Data 2a', 'Data 3a'), 
('Data 1b', 'Data 2b', 'Data 3b'), 
('Data 1c', 'Data 2c', 'Data 3c')
```

Answer (score 0):

You just use below code:

don't forgot about your all values in textarea is separated by comma.

```
 <?php

    $query = "insert into table (col1, col2, col3) values ";

    /*Get Post Data of Textarea*/
    $textarea = escape_string($_POST['yourTextArea']);

    /*replace values of */
    $getdata = str_replace("\r", "", str_replace("\n", "", $textarea));

    /* explode data to array */
    $data = explode(",", $textarea);

    /*create a empty array*/
    $dataForInsert = array();

    /*Set row start val*/
    $row = 1;

    foreach($data as $key=>$val){
       if(($key + 1) % 3 == 0){
            $row++;
       }
       $dataForInsert[$row][$key] = $val;
    }

    foreach($dataForInsert as $k=>$v){

        $query .= "("

        foreach($v as $k1=>$v1){
             if((count($v)-1) == $k1){
                 $query .= "'".$v1."'),";     
             }else{
                 $query .= "'".$v1."', ";
             }
        }

        if(count($dataForInsert) == $k){
            $query = substr($query, 0, strlen($query)-1);
        }
    }
    /* and use your query string here */
 ?>
```